# invalid literal for int() error / when loops for humongous numbers

Tags: python, string, while-loop

Continuing on with weeding out my misconceptions of Python fundamentals while trying to solve math problems. There are already working solutions for these floating around out there, I just want to see where I went wrong with mine. We need to find the largest product of five consecutive integers in a given 1000+ digit number. It stalls on the `product =` line with the `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error. I tried printing `product` outside of the loop and it multiplied everything just fine. So, something must be wrong with my while loop.

```
number = """73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"""

highest = None 

n = 0  
while n < 1000:
    product = (int(number[n]) * int(number[n + 1]) * int(number[n + 2]) 
             * int(number[n + 3]) * int(number[n + 4]))
    if highest is None or product > highest:
        highest = product
    n = n + 1

print highest
```

Comment: The issue is likely the newlines in your number. Try using a string of only digits, or replace `'\n'` with nothing in the string you have.

Comment: @devnull Yeah, I don't know how to go about that. I like to start working on these on my own (without looking at what others have done yet) and take them as far as I can myself and then ask questions that are more about my own code then finding the most efficient solution.

Comment: Also, ah, I had a feeling that doing a string that way will have some repercussions.

Comment: sivanes, I demonstrate how to set up your string so that you don't have to manipulate it.

Comment: I think my answer is better than the one on the other one. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `number` string has newline chars, `\n`, in it:

```
>>> number
'73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\n12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\n66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\n62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\n30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\n70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\n65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\n52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\n53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\n83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\n82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\n16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\n17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\n24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\n07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\n84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\n05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\n71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'
```

You can fix with:

```
number = ''.join(number.splitlines())
```

or

```
number = number.replace("\n", "")
```

and this works fine:

```
int(number)
```

If you want to set up your data without massaging it, you can use implicit concatenation:

```
number = ('73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934'
          '96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843'
          '85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511'
          #...
          )
```

Note the parentheses, and that there are no commas, so Python reads the lines as continuous. Don't escape the endlines, please.

Answer (score 0):

What happen is that you have new-line character in `number`. To solve this you can use:

```
number = ''.join(number.split("\n"))
```

Also, since you are accessing `number[n + 4]`, and the length of `number` is `1000`. You will have to loop in:

```
while n < 1000-4:
    ...
```

**Edit**

As @Blckknght and @isedev commented, a clearer way would be:

```
number = number.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: I'd think `number.replace("\n", "")` would be a bit more explicit.

Comment: @isedev `strip` removes trailing and leading characters, not in-middle ones.

Comment: Edited to show the more explicit way. Thanks for pointing that!